# Moxiemanager not opening browse window in dialog

Tags: tinymce, moxiemanager

I recently upgraded my moxiemanager tinymce plugin to the new 2.0 version. I use the Tinymce wysiwyg (4.1.9) in a jquery dialog popup. Everything seems to be working fine, until I click Upload > Local Machine to upload a new file. It will not open the browse window in any browser. I have cleared my cache and have exhausted Google for an answer and could not find anything. I also have striped out all other JavaScript includes to make sure it wasn't another piece causing the conflict. It does work if I place a tinymce instance on the main page. Has anyone seen anything like this before or have any tips to try?

Much appreciated!

Comment: UPDATE - I have also tried removing and re-initializing the tinymce instance after the dialog window loads. Also tried loading the tinymce instance on the main page then moving it to the dialog and neither have helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recently had the same issue...  It turns out that the Local Machine option on the Update button (in my latest version of MoxieManager, version 2.0.1) didn't play well with the old version of jQuery (1.72) that I was using.  Updating to the latest release of jQuery fixed the problem.

(The Support Team at MoxieManager quickly pointed this out to me when I opened a ticket and provided an example url of my problem.)

Comment: Gator, you are a saint! I was using jquery version 1.8.3 and upgraded it to 1.11.4 and it works now. I would one up you, but i don't have any reputation points. Also Moxie Support made it sound like I was the only one in the world with this issue. Thank you so much for commenting!